# Alcatel OneTouch 6040X not showing Camera as installed Application

Tags: android, alcatel-ot

i got a strange behaviour of my Alcatel which runs on Android 4.2.2.

Neither with

```
List<ApplicationInfo> myAppList = getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

nor with

```
List<PackageInfo> myAppList = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

do i get my Camera App. It's simply not showing up in the list. On a second device, which is a HTC, the Camera with the same code is inside the list.

Does someone have experience with this behaviour or does someone know a workaround or a suggestion.

**Update**

I also started a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27837790/how-to-get-applicationinfo-of-camera) with new `infos` but again it doesn't look promising.

The most important thing is that i get `Camera-App` as `ApplicationInfo`.

Would appreciate that.